# Can't display Ubuntu dock on only 1 monitor

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-dock

My Ubuntu dock was only displayed on my primary monitor.
Then, I set Settings > Appearance > Dock > Show on: All displays
Now, I can't change it back to my primary monitor.
I have 3 monitors. When I try to select either of my 2 secondary displays with the mouse, it stays on "All displays". When I select my primary monitor, the selection shows my primary monitor, but the dock is still displayed on all monitors.
If I close the window and reopen it, or try navigating to a different page and go back to the Appearance tab, it shows "All monitors" again.
I assume there's a settings file somewhere where I can manually fix it since the GUI is broken. But I don't know where.